# CREATE TABLE on BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How do I create a table on BigQuery from another existing table?

For example, I have a table:

```
col_1, col_2, val
...  , ...  , ...
```

And I want to create a new table as:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS (
SELECT col_1, SUM(val) AS sum_val FROM old_table) WITH DATA;
```

However, I cannot first query the result and then save the result because the result is too large.

Answer (score 7):

You should just use SELECT with respective destination parameters

```
SELECT col_1, SUM(val) AS sum_val FROM old_table
```

If you are doing this from within Web Ui  - they are "under" <kbd>Show Options</kbd> button
[image]

If you are using API - check [configuration.query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query) for respective properties

Answer (score 2):

Another way to make copy of existing table of Big query to new table there, just do

```
select * from [source_tbl_name]
```

Run it, just above right-hand side you can find ***"save as table"*** button.

> Click it and give the new table name. Your table will be created.

I used this to do the sampling from my bigger dataset for testing purpose.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score -4):

Couldn't you do something like:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
    (SELECT col_1, SUM(val) AS sum_val
     FROM   old_table
     GROUP BY something
     WHERE 1 > 2
     );
INSERT INTO new_table
    (SELECT col_1
          , SUM(val) AS sum_val
     FROM   old_table
     GROUP BY something
     );
```

(I noticed you are summing without a GROUP BY, so I fixed that bit for you (sort of).)

The CREATE TABLE would create the structure only (due to the 1>2 bit).  Then you could INSERT directly.